# This piece of code gets an error that those variables haven't been assgined to, and I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, list, static, filereader

I want to make a static List, but when I try read from file, and give the lists a value, it says that it haven't been assigned to, so its value is null.

```
class Log
    {   static public List<string> varos;
        static public List<int> tav;
        static public List<int> n;

        public void Input()
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader("vartav.txt");

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string s = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] seged = s.Split(' ');
                Log.varos.Add(seged[0]);
                Log.tav.Add(Convert.ToInt32(seged[1]));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *variable* is not an *object*, it is simply a placeholder for an object.  You are declaring the variables:

```
static public List<string> varos;
```

But you never initialized them to an object:

```
static public List<string> varos = new List<string>();
```

You could alternatively initialize them inside the method.  Though of course they wouldn't be initialized until that method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

**try initializing inside Input() method**

```
varos = new List<string>();
tav = new List<string>();
n = new List<string>();
```

**or initializie when u declare em**

```
static public List<string> varos = new List<string>();
static public List<string> tav = new List<string>();
static public List<string> n = new List<string>();
```

Comment: This looks like the correct answer, but this answer should be improved by explaining your suggestion works. For example, you are assigning values as you declare. Thanks for your contribution.